# The Hahn-Banach Separation Theorem for LCTVS

Tags: functional-analysis, locally-convex-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

I am currently reading through the text "Topological Vector Spaces" by Robertson, and I have come across the following proposition on page 29/30:

**Proposition 5.  (Hahn-Banach Separation theorem.)** Let $ E $ be a convex space.  Suppose that $ A $ and $ B $ are disjoint convex sets and that $ A $ is open.  Then there is a continuous linear form $ f $ such that $ f(A) $ and $ f(B) $ are disjoint ($ f $ separates $ A $ and $ B $).

(In this text, a convex space is just short for a locally convex topological vector space.)

The proof begins by stating that the set $ A - B $ is open and convex and does not contain the origin.

Unless I am missing something very trivial, isn't $ A - B = A $ since $ A $ and $ B $ are disjoint? Furthermore, why does $ A - B $ not contain the origin?

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $A - B$ probably means the set $\{ x - y \mid x \in A, y \in B \}$, rather than the set theoretic difference. This is open because it is the union of the sets $A - y$ for $y \in B$. I leave the proof of convexity to you.

If $0 \in A - B$, then there exist $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ such that $x - y = 0$, *i.e.* $x=  y$, contradicting the disjointness of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Oh yes!  You are absolutely right.  I completely overlooked this.  Thank you!